# Pycharm autocomplete doesn't work in conda env

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I have python2/python3 env on my local machine.
Python2 is installed in /usr/bin/python2.7, and python3 is installed with anaconda.

I set up python3/Django2.0 project, set up isolated env for Django with anaconda.

> conda create --name newapp

Activated new env.

> source activate newapp

And installed dependencies with pip3

> pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Python, Django version:

> python --version: Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc. 
>   django-admin.py version: 2.0.2

And, set python interpreter properly, as shown in the image.

[image]

But, pycharm autocomplete is not working for me. 
Pycharm autocomplete doesn't work with pip installed packages in anaconda environment? Is this something you faced before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have code completion turned on then. Go to **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Code Completion** (Or just search for "code completion" in settings) and make sure that the `Autopopup code completion` box is checked.